# Faster, inexpensive db compare tool than Schema Compare in Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I like the Schema Compare tool in Visual Studio okay but my biggest complaint is that it's just ridiculously slow when comparing our databases and I end up spending hours doing what would only take minutes if I wasn't constantly waiting for it to finish processing.

I don't need a lot of bells and whistles... just something that can show me what tables, views, procs, functions, and triggers have changed. Heck, I don't even care if it doesn't even highlight the differences in the objects just as long as it quickly tells me which objects differ.

Comment: Even though this is off topic (and voted as such) you might check out sql compare from redgate. It isn't free but it is a really solid product.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. $500 isn't really expensive for what it offers, but I don't have an extra $500 laying around right now. I'm hoping to find something more in the up to $150 range.

Comment: @BVernon, have you tried this: http://dbcomparer.com/

Comment: @FLICKER I actually just did. I set it to only compare the 5 object types mentioned in my post but after a few minutes the progress bar was not even 5% done. Not sure what's wrong but I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be that slow. I gave up and forcibly closed the application after a little while longer.

Comment: I'm trying dbForge Schema Comparer now. It's only $150. I'll post results in a few minutes...

Comment: Software can be cheap, fast or good. You get to pick two.

Comment: @SeanLange Unless it's funded by advertisements. Then you can get stuff like Google which is all three :) But seriously, there is a balance... and for me it looks like dbForge is going to be the balance I'm looking for. My experience with it so far is going great and it's inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a perfect fit for my price range and needs: https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/

Comment: I grabbed a copy of dbForge a few years ago because it handled ERDs against SQL Databases (Azure) well, where SSMS doesn't.  I still use SSMS primarily (with RedGate), but dbForge is reasonable.  Fairly solid with decent features for decent pricing.  I use it for uploading from excel sometimes also.